# Angular.js Controller can't set properties

Tags: html, model-view-controller, web, angularjs

I'm using a clone of https://github.com/angular/angular-seed to make a simple Angular.js app. I'm trying to put in some properties to the controllers in order to bind them in my HTML but keep getting errors messages that I can't seem to figure out.

My controllers.js file looks like this currently:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', [function($scope) {
    $scope.names = 'bob'
  }])
  .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

  }]);
```

Here is the app.js too if it helps:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives',     'myApp.controllers']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller:  'MyCtrl1'});
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
  }]);
```

I've used the default name for the app "myApp" and have also called the ng-view within my HTML. When MyCtrl1 is in use I continually get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'names' of undefined
```

Is there something syntactically wrong here? I've tried to only modify controllers.js to avoid having issues so there shouldn't be problems elsewhere...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Controllers has a few overloads, you can either simplify your code to this:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = 'bob'
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl2', function() {

  });
```

Or let Angular know what $scope is like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = 'bob'
  }])
  .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

  }]);
```

Reference: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller

Comment: Just a note here, I tried using the second example,(where $scope is referenced in the array), but I wasn't able to get it to work, only the first one seemed to work for me :S in case anyone else is trying to get the second one working.

Comment: @onaclov2000 It's probably a typo somewhere... do you have an example of it not working?  It works here with the most recent version: http://jsfiddle.net/hS9sn/ (the same code works with older ones as well).